# Как добавить платежную систему на Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, платежи

Есть сайт написанный на движке Smarty.
Есть проблема. Как добавить платежную систему там ?

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: smarty это не движок для написания сайтов, а шаблонизатор. Так что в контексте смарти говорить можно лишь о добавлении иконки платежной системы  в шаблон.

Comment: ок а как и это сделать ?

Comment: у платежек часто бывает возможность генерировать html код формы на оплату. просто найдите нужную страницу в файлах шаблона и скопируйте туда эту форму.